# Extract decimal number from an alphanumeric string in Excel VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I am really new to excel VBA and struggling to write a function which can extract a decimal number from an alphanumerical string like 1.25/g or 23.5g etc. The decimal number will always be in front.

I found some solutions to the problem but they don't apply to decimal numbers.

I found a solution which works for some strings but doesn't work for all. I have posted the function below. Its returning 1.2 g as 1, but works for a lot of other numbers.

Thanks in advance.

```
Public Function first_try(a) As Double

Dim i As Long

For i = 1 To Len(a)
If IsNumeric(Mid(a, i, 1)) Then    
    first_try = Val(Mid(a, i))
        Exit For
    End If
Next i

Debug.Print firt_try

End Function
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, a shortcut could be [`Val`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/val-function) function.

```
Public Function first_try(a) As Double
    first_try = Val(a)
End Function
```

As per documentation:

> *"The Val function stops reading the string at the first character that it can't recognize as part of a number."*